# Why in Asp.Net Identity 2.0 PhoneNumber is [nvarchar](max)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, optimization, asp.net-identity

I am using Asp.Net Identity 2.0 in my MVC 5 project.

Why is column `PhoneNumber` using `[nvarchar](max)` in SQL Server database table `[dbo].[AspNetUsers]`?

Can I change this to `[nvarchar](64)`, for example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created a class `ApplicationUser : IdentityUser` in which I override property `PhoneNumber` with attribute `[MaxLength(64)]`.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public override string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to specify custom length using the modelBuilder in the ApplicationDbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {

    }

    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        // Set the database intializer which is run once during application start
        // This seeds the database with admin user credentials and admin role
        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
        .Where(x => x.Name == "PhoneNumber")
        .Configure(c => c.HasMaxLength(64));
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

I have tested it and it works!

For more information about manipulating EF6 mappings you can check out this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164#classes

Comment: Does it work now? please accept this as an answer if it works and you don't have any additional questions etc.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I found other way to do the same. I created class `ApplicationUser : IdentityUser` in which I override property `PhoneNumber` with attribute `[MaxLength(64)]`.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can change, just limit nvarchar if you dont want to exceed that number because data store size of nvarchar is equal to  two times the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes.
ex :  max or 64 wont effect size if you enter 5 char string